# In the Vim omni-completion popup menu, is there a way to have long suggestions wrap instead of be truncated?

Tags: vim

I'm working with a library that has some very verbose type signatures that are being cut short in the suggestions menu. Is there some setting I can use that will let me see the full type signatures even if my terminal window is not wide enough? Perhaps by using word wrapping and multiple lines per menu item?

[image]

Comment: No. I would say it's impossible. But you could try `:set completeopt+=preview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want longer suggestions, you need to increase the width of your terminal. Vim's completion popup is limited to single lines, wrapping isn't implemented. For longer suggestions (like function prototypes), the value `preview` in `'completeopt'` can be specified (though this isn't actually populated by many completions).